# ServiceLocator Current GetInstance?

Tags: service-locator, prism-6

I have assemblies discovered in a directory using MEF and they are loaded when needed during runtime when a user selects a menu.

[image: The MainMenuListViewModel OnMainMenuSelectionChanged()]

After a assembly is loaded each has its own UI and views can be added to it as the user needs them, but when I use **excelView = ServiceLocator.Current.GetInstance();** I get an exception.

[image: The ExcelController ShowExcelView()]

Exception Details
[image: Exception Details on ServiceLocator.Current.GetInstance]

How do I solved this problem, because I'm assuming directory discovered assembles are added to the **AggregateCatalog** so the **ServiceLocator** can find them right?

This is how the main IExcelView is setup:
[image]

Answer (score 1):

I found the problem, I needed to add the *Key* I used to *Export* the class.

[image]